# Text to integer

Tags: vb.net, text, numbers, integer

I want to make a program in vb.net which turns words into numbers, for example in the sentence "Hello my name is Ben Hello" it would turn into "1 2 3 4 5 1". I'm not really sure how to go about it, any help?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and the [FAQ] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: There's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000471/program-that-identifies-words-in-a-sentence-stores-these-in-a-list-and-replaces/40001909#40001909) exactly like this and I answered it, also asked by someone named ben...wierd.

Comment: Could you link me it?

Comment: @bensy If you look at soohoonigan's comment, you should see that "another question" is the link you want.

Answer (score 2):

create a dictionary. if the item exist print its index if not add it to the dictionary and than print its index

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Dim AscVals As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello my name is Ben Hello")

       Dim result As String = String.Empty
       For Each byt As Byte In AscVals
           result += byt.ToString
       Next

       MessageBox.Show(result)

   End Sub
```